# How to handle a popup in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I'm automating an application where on clicking a button a popup opens up , I am a bit confused about handling this popup.I am attaching the screenshot below where i have to handle the " Daily Trip details" popup. Can it be handled by driver.getwindowhandles() code or autoit?Thanks

Image of the popup:
[image: Image]]

Comment: Looks like a `modal` to me. Check the `DOM` if a `modal` gets opened. If it is one you can just find the elements like you normally would.

Comment: yes it says Modal in the DOM.... and what do you mean by if a modal gets opened?

Comment: Something on your webpage will trigger the `modal` to appear. Probably a click on a button. What do you want to achieve? Do you want to close the `modal` or do you want to modify the `textfields` and submit it?

Comment: yes i need to fill the fields present in that popup and submit it

Comment: Ok. So you should be able to just `find` the fields and fill them with text like you normally would do on a webpage.

Comment: alright i'll try that.. thanks..

Comment: If you see a popup, right-click on it. If the typical page context menu comes up and you see Inspect element, then it's an HTML dialog. Treat it like any other HTML on the page. If the context menu doesn't come up, then it's possibly/probably a JS dialog and you can use the `Alert` class.

Comment: i tried the above but it didnt work , giving me Element not visible exception

Answer (score -1):

You can handle using getWindowHadles(). After switching to new window you can perform actions which are required for your test case.
Following code may help you out for switching to modal

```
   String currentWindowHandle=driver.getWindowHandle();
    for(String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
        if(!windowHandle.equals(currentWindowHandle)){
            driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          //perform actions which are required 
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is a dialog, not another browser instance so your code will not work.

Comment: the above code is for handling a different window popup but the one i have shown is a different one